# Multiple class name in variable

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to use multiple class inside a variable using the [Interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) method.

This method work for me if I have one class and I use it like this:

```
$class: classname1;

.#{class} {
   color: red;
}
```

But if I want to use more the one class I have a problem:

```
$class: classname1.classname2;

.#{class} {
   color: red;
}
```

This snippet give me an error because of the dot inside the variable. I tried some other options but nothing worked.

Any idea how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use a string as a variable

```
$class: ".classname1.classname2";

#{$class} {
   color: red;
}
```

(tested on [sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com))